# Django with GDAL throwing error when deploying on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I deploy my Django app with Heroku there seems to be some problem with GDAL. When I run `heroku logs --tail` I get the following:

```
[...]
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792392+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 6, in <module>
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792393+00:00 app[web.1]: from .features import DatabaseFeatures
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792393+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/features.py", line 1, in <module>
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792394+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792394+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base/features.py", line 3, in <module>
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792394+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.contrib.gis.db import models
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792395+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792395+00:00 app[web.1]: import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792395+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py", line 3, in <module>
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792396+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792401+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792401+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792402+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792402+00:00 app[web.1]: from .fields import (  # NOQA
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792402+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py", line 2, in <module>
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792402+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792403+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792406+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792407+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 40, in <module>
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792407+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792407+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792407+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792408+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 9, in <module>
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792408+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792408+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 53, in <module>
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792409+00:00 app[web.1]: lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792409+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792409+00:00 app[web.1]: self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792409+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: /opt/homebrew/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.dylib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-01-14T11:20:56.792410+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-14 11:20:56 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-01-14T11:20:56.895552+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-14 11:20:56 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-01-14T11:20:56.993856+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-14 11:20:56 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-01-14T11:20:56.993930+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-14 11:20:56 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2022-01-14T11:20:57.168821+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
[...]
```

I'm using a PostgreSQL database with `postgis` enabled (it is a geolocation app).

I've installed this [buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack) and my `requirements.txt` file has `GDAL==2.4.0` in there (which aligns with the version the buildpack appears to install).

My understanding of `dylibs` is that they are a MACOS filetype - therefore `Heroku` is pointing to my local machine for `GDAL` rather than a `Heroku dyno`, I'm fairly new to all this but I believe I need to figure out why this is happening and how to change where Heroku is searching for `GDAL`.

Requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.4.1
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.10
cryptography==36.0.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==4.0.1
django-allauth==0.47.0
django-bootstrap-modal-forms==2.2.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-on-heroku==1.1.2
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.11
djangorestframework==3.13.1
GDAL==2.4.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.3
oauthlib==3.1.1
psycopg2==2.9.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.3.0
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2021.3
requests==2.27.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
soupsieve==2.3.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
urllib3==1.26.8
whitenoise==5.3.0
```

Comment: Please [edit] and show your `requirements.txt`. `GDAL 2.4.0` isn't a valid entry; it should be something like `gdal==2.4.0`. And Heroku doesn't use homebrew, so something funky is going on here. Did you try to copy GDAL from a macOS machine somehow? Have you committed that library, or your virtual environment?

Comment: Thanks - fixed typo in OP and added requriements.txt. I used ``brew install`` and ``pip3 install`` as a bit of a desperation move to see if ``GDAL`` could be installed that way. But it didn't make a difference. ``GDAL`` appears in ``pip3 list`` in my ``venv``

Comment: You used `brew install` and `pip3 install`... where? On your local machine? For some reason _Heroku_ is referencing homebrew. Is your virtual environment committed?

Comment: Yes on my local machine. I believe my ``venv`` is committed - the rest of the dependencies install fine watching the deployment log

Comment: Your virtual environment should _not_ be committed. That's part of the problem: you're pushing a GDAL compiled for macOS to Heroku, which runs Linux. Where is it? In a `.venv/` folder? Just `venv/`? Somewhere else?

Comment: I see it is in my apps root directory  as `venv/` same level as `Procfile` etc.

Comment: If you're pushing that, it's at least part of the problem. Untrack it with `git rm -r --cached venv/`, then commit (e.g. "Remove virtual environment from repository"), then deploy again. If that works I'll write up a proper answer.

Comment: Sorry, but that returns this error: ``fatal: pathspec 'venv' did not match any files`` when I run ``ls`` in my ``root`` directory it shows ``venv`` as there.

Comment: So it _isn't_ committed? Try `git ls-files venv`. I'm really confused at how Heroku is getting a library linked against Homebrew stuff...

Comment: nothing happens when i run that. Yeah - beginner bad luck...

Comment: If by "nothing happens" you mean "there's no output", that means nothing in that directory is committed.

Comment: That's correct - no outut

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241094/discussion-between-deadant88-and-chris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, how I fixed this:

1. Make sure there is nothing funky to do with GDAL in your `settings.py` - I had followed [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412950/gdal-configuration-for-django-in-mac-gdal-library-path-exception) answer to get GDAL working on my local server during development and had to delete it the Paths from my `settings.py`
2. `pip uninstall GDAL`
3. `pip freeze > requirements. txt`
4. Add the `heroku-geo-buildpack` ([link](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack)) and make sure it is set as the first `buildpack` for your app
5. `git commit` all your changes
6. Push the app again