# Got the error "python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully" while trying to deploy my Django app to Heroku. What could it be?

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, gdal, heroku-cli

I'm trying to deploy my GeoDjango app to Heroku.

First of all, I'm using the **[Heroku Geo Buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack)** and followed the instructions both in the related GitHub repo and **[here](https://help.heroku.com/D5INLB1A/python-s-build_with_geo_libraries-legacy-feature-is-no-longer-supported)**.

I got the mentioned error and tried to search for answers. I took a look at **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70709904/django-with-gdal-throwing-error-when-deploying-on-heroku/70778994#70778994)**, and tried but the same error comes up every single time. The project is built on Python 3.7.10 - I even tried **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72588717/i-get-an-error-when-trying-to-deploy-python-fastapi-on-heroku)** and changed the Python version to 3.9.13 (**[Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version)**) but nothing.

I also get this error **"error in GDAL setup command: use_2to3 is invalid."** Additionally, it says **Numpy not available** but I later installed it and refreshed the requirements.txt file.

**The error I get in detail:**

```
remote:        Collecting GDAL==2.4.2
remote:          Downloading GDAL-2.4.2.tar.gz (564 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
remote:          error: subprocess-exited-with-error
remote:
remote:          × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
remote:          │ exit code: 1
remote:          ╰─> [6 lines of output]
remote:              WARNING: numpy not available!  Array support will not be enabled
remote:              /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'use_2to3_fixers'
remote:                warnings.warn(msg)
remote:              /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'use_2to3_exclude_fixers'
remote:                warnings.warn(msg)
remote:              error in GDAL setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
remote:              [end of output]
remote:
remote:          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
remote:        error: metadata-generation-failed
remote:
remote:        × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
remote:        ╰─> See above for output.
remote:
remote:        note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
remote:        hint: See above for details.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to project
```

**Requirements .txt:**

```
asgiref==3.5.2
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
certifi==2022.6.15
charset-normalizer==2.1.0
dj-database-url==1.0.0
Django==3.2.14
django-cors-headers==3.13.0
django-filter==22.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
djangorestframework==3.13.1
djangorestframework-gis==1.0
docopt==0.6.2
GDAL==2.4.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.3
Js2Py==0.71
numpy==1.21.6
packaging==21.3
pipwin==0.5.2
psycopg2==2.9.3
pyjsparser==2.7.1
pyparsing==3.0.9
PyPrind==2.11.3
pySmartDL==1.3.4
python-dotenv==0.20.0
pytz==2022.1
pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
requests==2.28.1
Shapely==1.8.2
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
sqlparse==0.4.2
typing_extensions==4.3.0
tzdata==2022.1
tzlocal==4.2
urllib3==1.26.11
whitenoise==6.2.0
```

**So, I really need help on this.
Thanks.**

Comment: You will need to make sure your python gdal version matches the gdal binaries provided by the heroku environment (I am not a heroku user). Also, why are you holding back your gdal version ? Ver 3 is standard now and ver 2 has not been updated in a long while.

Comment: Well, Heroku supports GDAL 2.4.0 / 2.4.2 / 3.5.0 and I’ve tried all of these. However, I’ve used 2.4.1 version for the development. In addition, GDAL 3 version had some problems with my Django app therefore I needed to downgrade it to 2.4.1.

Comment: Obvious question, but does your app work locally with this requirements.txt ?

Comment: Yes it does. I was in a position where I needed to be sure that it works locally. That's when I've attempted to deploy it on Heroku.

Comment: I would think about using conda environments instead. The gdal binaries are installed into the conda environment along with the python package, ensuring there is no mismatch. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949173/deploy-a-python-dash-app-to-heroku-using-conda-environments-instead-of-virtua